# How to derive energy dependent Gamma and Delta of topological nanowire?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, topological-insulators

I read two articles,

> G. Tkachov, and E. M. Hankiewicz. “Spin-helical transport in normal and superconducting topological insulators.” physica status solidi (b) 250, no. 2 (2013): 215. ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1466))
>
> G. Tkachov “Suppression of surface p-wave superconductivity in disordered topological insulators” Phys. Rev. B 87, 245422 (2013)([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0631))

In first article, equation (76),(77) and (78) shows $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ dependence on energy according to McMillan's model.  In that paper, the model is 2 dimensional, therefore for 1 dimensional  case the $\hbar v\sigma\cdot\hat{k}\rightarrow\hbar vk_x$ in equation (78).  The article does not describe how $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ dependence on energy are derived. It just refers to an McMillan's article that is not freely accessible. The second article shows more details (see equations 17-23), but still I am struggling with algebra on how to derive $\Delta(\epsilon)$ and $\Gamma(\epsilon)$.  I am trying to adapt Tkachov model to one dimensional case (nanowire).  Does $(k,k')$ represent momentum in (first,second) dimension in equation (1)? What $k'$ stands for? Second dimension or second system? After reading second article, it seems to me that if I want to describe topological superconducting nanowire in Nambu space as a Green's function (1D system instead 2D system) equation (35) is sufficient and equation (32) the second equation becomes $\hbar v_n(k-k_n)\rightarrow\hbar v_n(k_x-k_n)$ and there are no Pauli matrices involved. Is my assumption/approach correct?  In equation (35) the denominator is not under squareroot which means it is not normalized. What is the significance of it?

Comment: @FraSchelle, thanks for constructive comment.  I did modify the question, added more description and another article in order to be more clear to readers. I am interesting in developing a Green's function of topological superconducting nanowire.

Comment: Now I understand you're new on this website. It seems difficult for me to believe you want to describe a superconducting nanowire to enjoy yourself. I believe it's an academic project you have. If I'm correct, it means you have a supervisor who is certainly a scholar. It is difficult to believe (s)he has no access to articles published in Physical Review and can help you with MacMillan's paper. Also, your question is by far too specific to interest anyone else on physics.SE. Moreover your notations are never defined. I suggest you to first ask your supervisor before posting something here.